# Matching and returning rows in php and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, while-loop

I would love to get some help with this. I'm using php and MySQL to build a website. I currently have 3 tables, I'll include less in the examples. Basically I have a users table, a groups table and a grouplink table. What I have is the uid from the users table.

How should I go about it in php so I could, let's say: match users-uid to grouplink-uid, get the grouplink-gid it matches with, match grouplink-gid to groups-gid and return groups-grpname? And goes on a while loop so all group names the user is associated with are displayed.

Thanks in advance to those who will be willing to extend a hand.

**users**

```
-------
| uid |
-------
|  1  |
-------
```

**groups**

```
---------------
| gid |grpname|
---------------
|  1  | grp1  |
---------------
|  2  | grp2  |
---------------
```

**grouplink**

```
-------------------
| glid| uid | gid |
-------------------
|  1  |  1  |  1  |
-------------------
|  2  |  1  |  2  |
-------------------
```

*uid is fk to uid in users while gid is fk to gid in groups*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just a simple 2-way join query:

```
SELECT users.uid, groups.gid, groups.grpname
FROM users
INNER JOIN grouplink ON users.uid = grouplink.uid
INNER JOIN groups ON grouplink.gid = groups.gid
```

the actual retrieval of a joined query result is no different than a single table query - you've just got more fields to deal with.

Comment: Ahh, INNER JOINS. One topic I skipped whilst learning MySQL. Oh well, look at the price I had to pay. Good thing there's this place. Thanks, bud.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL query that will get you what you're looking for goes something like this (assuming no null values in the grouplink table):

```
SELECT u.uid, g.gid, g.grpname
FROM users u
JOIN grouplink gl ON u.uid = gl.uid
JOIN groups g ON gl.gid = g.gid
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
SELECT users.uid, groups.gid, groups.grpname
FROM users u, groups g, grouplink gl
WHERE g.id = gl.gid
AND gl.uid = u.uid
```

Answer (score 1):

When the user-id is in the variable `$iUserId` you could query following sql string:

```
$sSql = "SELECT groups.`grpname` FROM groups
    INNER JOIN grouplink ON groups.`gid` = grouplink.`gid`
    WHERE grouplink.`uid` = '" . intval($iUserId) . "'";
$rRes = mysql_query($sSql);
$aGroups = array();
while (($aRow = mysql_fetch_array($rRes)) !== false) {
   $aGroups[] = $aRow['grpname'];
}
```

Now all groups associated with the user are in the array `$aGroups`.